# Insert an image that already exists in the project folder

Tags: css, eclipse

I have this image in one of my project's folder: 
[image]

I wantto make a icon with that image, so i tried to call it like this:
[image]

But it keeps occuring the error:

[image]

I think I have this error because I'm not giving any path.

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css file is searching in the same folder as it to find the background image.

Try:

```
background: url("../img/Arrow_Circle_Right-32.png")
```

The ".." goes back one folder, then the img accesses the image folder.

Answer (score 1):

Use this path in your `css`:

```
background: #ff9900 url("../img/Arrow_Circle_Right-32.png") no-repeat 10px center;
```

Please note the prefix for your base path: `../img/`

Like that you go back from the `css` directory and then you enter in your `img` directory, that include your image.

Comment: please consider the `../` that I missed the first time and that I corrected